# sql to sum counts and add amounts from 2 tables

Tags: sql

I am having getting the last sql to work.

The first two grouping gave me the right answer but the last one which involves joining 2 tables gave me a number thats too high when i manually add the first two together.

sql is to generate figures 1,2 and the (1+2) as 3.

Pls help.
sql below....

```
select      [OrderDate]     as "Date", 
            'Cobs'          as "Payment Source", 
            COUNT(*)        as "Quantity", 
            SUM([Amount])   as "Value in Pounds"
from        cobaltins
where       PN like 'BT%'
group by    OrderDate

union all

select      [OrderDate]     as "Date", 
            'Cobs Adhoc'    as "Payment Source",
            COUNT(*)        as "Quantity", 
            SUM([Amount])   as "Value in Pounds"
FROM        cobaltins_adhoc
where       name = 'Vauz'
group by    OrderDate

union all

select      cba.OrderDate   as "Date", 
            'Cumulative'    as "Payment Source",
            COUNT(*)        as "Quantity", 
            sum((cb.Amount)+(cba.Amount)) as "Value in Pounds"
FROM        cobaltins       as cb 
left join   cobaltins_adhoc as cba  on cb.OrderDate = cba.OrderDate
where       cb.PN like 'BT%' 
    or      cba.name = 'Vauz'
group by    cba.OrderDate
```

Comment: One thing that pops out to me is the left join below.  I'm not exactly sure what the tables are, but could it be holding onto too many values and skewing the results by counting some twice?  Maybe an inner join is more appropriate?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than try and get it in one you might want to try and sum an inline view of your UNION

```
SELECT 
        "Date", 
        "Payment Source", 
         SUM(Quantity) Quantity,
         SUM("Value in Pounds") "Value in Pounds"
 FROM 
(
        select  [OrderDate] as "Date",
                  'Cobs' as "Payment Source", 
                COUNT(*) as "Quantity",
             SUM([Amount]) as "Value in Pounds"
         from cobaltins
         where PN like 'BT%'
         group by OrderDate

        union all

        select [OrderDate] as "Date", '
               Cobs Adhoc' as "Payment Source",COUNT(*) as "Quantity", 
               SUM([Amount]) as "Value in Pounds"
        FROM cobaltins_adhoc
         where name = 'Vauz'
        group by OrderDate
) t 
GROUP BY 
        "Date", 
        "Payment Source"
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are doing your join

```
FROM cobaltins as cb
LEFT JOIN cobaltins_adhoc as cba
ON cb.OrderDate = cba.OrderDate
```

is only joining on the order date. if you have multiple orders per date then it's going to try to join those together arbitrarily. you will want to add something else into that join to make it distinct.

Comment: The 2 tables has nothing else in common..I just want to get a sum of the 2 money made from each table and the counts..

Comment: in that case i would suggest using the answer above by Conrad Frix, which has the two as subqueries and then aggregates their values. because that would allow you to only get the individual values that you want instead of having the join duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining on OrderDate.

That means if there is more than one row in either table with the same order date, then you will get duplication of the matching rows in the other table.

A quick way to test this is to remove the COUNT(*) and the GROUP BY, and just look at the result of your join.   Do you see any duplicates that you didn't want to count?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this with columns instead of rows?

```
select bt."Date", bt.Quantity as Cobs, vauz.Quantity as CobsAdhoc,
       (bt.quantity + coalesce(vauz.Quantity)) as Total
from (select [OrderDate] as "Date", 'Cobs' as "Payment Source", COUNT(*) as "Quantity",
             SUM([Amount]) as "Value in Pounds"
      from cobaltins
      where PN like 'BT%'
      group by OrderDate
     ) bt left outer join
     (select [OrderDate] as "Date", 'Cobs Adhoc' as "Payment Source",COUNT(*) as "Quantity", 
             SUM([Amount]) as "Value in Pounds"
      FROM cobaltins_adhoc
      where name = 'Vauz'
      group by OrderDate
     ) vauz
     on bt."Date" = vauz."Date";
```